# Code style guide for JSF Expression Language

Tags: java, jsf, coding-style, el, code-standards

Are there any code conventions/standards or recommendations for formatting JSF Expression Language?

Answer (score 0):

I guess HTML conventions can be applied to JSF EL too, or at least that's what I'm doing. Just indent and organize your code nicely; the IDE's auto-indent feature should also help you out in this: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in NetBeans and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use [Java2Html](http://www.java2html.de/) code beautifier.It can also use with eclipse.